# Dynamic Code - C#

Tags: c#, architecture

We are developing a product that will be deployed for a number of clients. In an area of this product, we need to execute some formulas. The problem is that this formulas can be different for each client. So we need to have a good architecture that can 'execute code dynamically'

The application is a web application hosted on sharepoint 2010 (thereby using .net 3.5)

A Simplified example: 
I have class MyClassA  with two numeric properties PropA and PropB
For one client the formula is PropA + PropB. For the other it is PropA-PropB.
*This is just a simplified example as the formula is more complex than this.*

I need to have a way that client A we can set PropA+PropB  perhaps in an XMl file or database.
I would then load the code dynamically?

Does this make sense? Has anyone implement similar scenario in a production environment please?

I have found that the following article describes a similar situation but I do not know whether it is 100% reliable for a production environment:
http://west-wind.com/presentations/dynamicCode/DynamicCode.htm

I have also found that IronPython can also solve a similar problem but I cannot understand how I would use my ClassA with IronPython.

Any assistance would be greately appreciated.

Update ... 
Thanks everyone for the detailed feedback. It was a very constructive exercise. I have reviewed the different approaches and it seems very likely that we will go ahead with the nCalc approach. nCalc seems to be a wonderful tool and I am already loving the technology :) 
Thank you all!!

Comment: For simple formulas there is ncalc. For complex cases you could compile C# at runtime.

Comment: Have you considered MEF? You could use a plugin architecture do load the client specific assemblies.

Comment: While not super sexy - what if you write your own parser that accepts a formula as a string (or a formula builder). Then essentially pop PropA in where it says PropA? Stupid simple (probably too simple) is to have something like `var formula = "A - B"; formula.Replace("A", PropA).Replace("B", PropB)`. Then run your custom parser to do A minus B - there are probably good libraries for the math part

Comment: Do you have any info about user? User's role in system? Then you can calculate your form based on this information about user. I still do not understand why you need to dynamic code executing.

Comment: If the formulas don't change, you might be better off with the strategy pattern.  For example, you could have an `AddStrategy` and a `SubstractStrategy` and select the correct one for a given client based on persisted data.  For more complex formulas this might prove too complex, however; in that case you might also look at expression trees as a way of helping you "compile code at runtime" as CodeInChaos suggested.

Comment: CodeInChaos - thanks, I will investigate ncalc but formula are a bit complex so compiling c# is an option.

Comment: phoog - thanks for your reply. Formulas are a bit complex (they are client specific), so strategy pattern may not work here.

Comment: Simon - formula is quite complex made up of different parameters and it is specific for clients and new clients will be added in the system. So a good architecture with some form of dynamic nature is necessary here.

Comment: What I would do is to have IFormula interface which holds a "representation" of formula. Then inject the right implementation at the run time. The implementaion could be either (1) hard coded for each customer, or (2) you can make it dynamic by using nCalc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into [nCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/).

You could store your calculations in a database field then simply execute them on demand.  Pretty simple and powerful.  We are using this in a multi-tenant environment to help with similar types of customization.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just proposing this because I don't know the problem very well but the idea could be a Dll for each formula (so you can handle the code as you wish, with normal C# functionalities instead of an uncomfortable xml file).

With [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) you can inject dll into your code (you just have to upload those when you develop a new one, no need to recompile the exe file) and have a different formula for each client.

This is my idea because it looks like a perfect example for [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Comment: MEF looks like the most clean solution. I will need to investigate how to integrate in .net 3.5 and sharepoint but I think it is doable. I like the idea of being able to inject code dynamically for this. And it could be especially appropriate for this case because this is something that most likely developers will change and not users. (although it would be nice if users could change the formulas but not really a requirement)

Comment: If user should have the possibility to change formulas (you have to handle exception very well obviusly), I think Chris answer is the better one

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a fixed set of formulas, or does the client have the capacity to dynamically type those in, i.e. as for a calculator?
In the first case, I'd recommend the following: set of C# delegates, which get called/call each other in a particular order, and (a) Dictionary(ies) of closures which fit the delegates. The closures would then be assigned to the delegates based on your predefined conditions.

In the alternative case, I wouldn't compile .NET code based on what the client types in, since that (unless preempted) represents a server-side security risk. I would implement/adapt a simple parser for expressions that you're expecting.

P.S. [nCalc](http://ttp://ncalc.codeplex.com/) sugguested by Chris Lively is definitely a viable option for this kind of task, and is better than directly using delegates if you have tons and tons of formulas that you don't want to keep in memory.

Comment: thanks for your reply. ... I hadn't thought about the security aspects. but they are very important in this case. I will investigate nCalc as I have never used it before.

Comment: Glad to help, but nCalc was really Chris's answer. I left him a + 1 to  complement, I can't take credit for that.

Answer (score 0):

ClassA with Ironpython?
Keep it simple

Run through the classA instance for each member (maybe a custom attribute to mark up the ones you want to use in the calc) and end up with name=value pair which by some unfortunate coincidence looks like an assignment

e.g

```
PropA = 100
PropB = 200
```

Prepend that to your python script

```
PropAPropB = PropA + PropB
```

Execute the script which is the assignments and the calculation

Then it's basically

```
ClassB.PropAPropB = ipCalc.Eval("PropAPropB");
```

You can start getting real clever with it, but a methods to get the inputs from an instance and one the evaluatios the result of the calc and sets teh properties.

Bob's your mother's sister's brother...